# installing linux on flash drive while some computers have dual boot of win/linux

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, grub2, usb-drive

.Hi everybody,

I have a laptop that has **512 GB SSD** hard drive! it has **dual boot** of 350 GB for windows and 150GB for Linux( *ubuntu 18.04* )

SO now today I bought a ***128GB Samsung flash drive*** and I want it to be ***  portable * for my Linux purposes (i want a flash drive which has Ubuntu 18.04 )**

I installed Ubuntu on the flash drive ( 18.04 ), but can not load this new Ubuntu from flash and there is no sign of new Ubuntu on the grub! ( I did grub_update )

[image]

when I wanted to install new ubuntu on flash Drive, ***Set 80GB for /, 40 GB for /home, 500MB for /boot, 300MB for UEFI!***           ( is there something wrong here? ) what is the proper config for installing on flash while some devices have already dual boot drive and flash cant be loaded on them

Here is the flash drive image

[image]

Thanks
.
Regard

Comment: This method of creating Full install USB works for me with 18.04, both BIOS and UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: C.S.Cameron beat me by two minutes :-) This is an alternative: If you want a **portable** installed system in the 128 GB SSD, you had better unplug or otherwise disable the internal drive before you start the installation (or do the installation in another computer if it is difficult to unplug/disable the internal drive in one computer). Then perform the installation according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312).